# how to delete certain lines in a text file without looping

Tags: python-3.x

is there any way that I can delete certain lines in a text file without having to use any loops and in basic python language?. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: yes, if you know the contents of the file. By knowing the line only it's difficult without a loop. What is your input?

Comment: If you know exactly what you're looking for then you could read the entire file and then use str.replace

Comment: basically is a login program that uses text file as it main storage. So for example if there are 20 lines in a text file is there any way I can delete line 5 to 10. Thanks